# How to fix Scala http request addHeader not working

Tags: scala, http, akka, seq

My usecase is copy some of the headers of the current http request to the new request i am making. However it does not work , Can you let me know what is the issue or any alternatives.

```
  private def apiPostRequest(path:String, host: HostStoreInfo, byteString:ByteString , prevRequest:HttpRequest):Future[HttpResponse] = {
    val request = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST,s"http://${host.host}:${host.port}$path",Nil,HttpEntity.apply(byteString))
    logger.info("Previous request  "+prevRequest)
    if(prevRequest!=null) {
      for(h<-prevRequest.headers) { //Copying over to new request
        logger.info("header  "+h)
        request.addHeader(h)
      }
    }
    logger.info("Here are the headers "+request.headers). // coming as null
    Http().singleRequest(request)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Requests (like most good things in scala) are immutable. `.addHeader` returns a *new request* with the header added.

Try this:

```
val request = Option(prevRequest)// prevRequest should actually be Option[HttpRequest] to begin with. Using nulls is code smell!
  .toSeq
  .flatMap(_.headers)
  .foldLeft(
    HttpRequest(
      HttpMethods.POST,
      s"http://${host.host}:${host.port}$path",
      Nil,
      HttpEntity(byteString)
    )
   ) { _ addHeader _ }
```

Or better yet, just this:

```
   val request = HttpRequest(
      HttpMethods.POST,
      s"http://${host.host}:${host.port}$path",
      Option(prevRequest).toSeq.flatMap(_.headers),
      HttpEntity(byteString)
    )
```

Comment: [ERROR]  found   : Seq[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpHeader]
[ERROR]  required: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpHeader]
[ERROR]       Option(prevRequest).toSeq.flatMap(_.headers),
[ERROR]                                        ^
[ERROR] one error found

Getting the following error while trying second option

Comment: @hareendrareddy I dunno ... [works for me](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/r3RP5lTLR9uIoWQ5z6h6uQ)